# Salted-hashed password verification is not working

Tags: java, authentication, salt

I have built a function to hash the users password when they register using my java application. I am not sure how I should go about trying to verify their login since the password stored is going to be hashed.

I have tried making a function, that takes the entered password and hashes it and then compares the hash to the one in the database but, this didn't work since each time the hashing function is run on a password (String) the result is never the same. I am not sure how to verify the users password on login. Below I have provided:

- Login button code
- Generating secure password using salt function
- Verification function

Login button code:

```
try {
    // Get password from database and verify login
    String slt = passwordUtils.getSalt(100);
    Connection con = connectDB.getConnectionUser();
    Statement stmt = null;
    
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM USER where userEmail=?";
    PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(1, userEmail.getText());
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
    
    String fromDatabase = rs.getString(3); //get the password stored in database (hashed version)
    String enteredPassword = String.valueOf(userPassword.getPassword()); //get entered password
    
    if(rs.next()){
        if(passwordUtils.verifyUserPassword(enteredPassword, fromDatabase, slt)){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login details are correct. Welcome!");
            con.close();
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Log in details, try again.");
            con.close();
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Generate secure password function

```
public static String generateSecurePassword(String password, String salt){
    String returnValue = null;
    System.out.println("password supplied is: " + password + "salt added: " + salt);
    System.out.println("");
    byte[] securePassword = hash(password.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes());
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("secure pwd byte[]: " + securePassword);
    System.out.println("");
    returnValue = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(securePassword);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("secure pwd converted " + returnValue);
    return returnValue;
}
```

Verify login function

```
public static boolean verifyUserPassword(String providedPassword, String securedPassword, String salt){
    boolean returnValue = false;
    // generate new secure password with same salt
    String newSecurePassword = generateSecurePassword(providedPassword, salt); //generate secure password using salt 
    //check to see if both passwords are the same
    returnValue = newSecurePassword.equalsIgnoreCase(securedPassword);
    
    System.out.println("Hashed password: " + securedPassword);
    System.out.println("Verify hash:     "+ newSecurePassword);
   
    return returnValue;
}
```

Salting function

```
public static String getSalt(int length){;
    StringBuilder returnValue = new StringBuilder(length);
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        returnValue.append(ALPHABET.charAt(RANDOM.nextInt(ALPHABET.length())));
    }
    System.out.println("final salt generated: " + returnValue);
    return new String(returnValue);
}
```

Hashing function:

```
public static byte[] hash(char[] password, byte[] salt){
    PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, ITERATIONS, KEY_LENGTH);
    Arrays.fill(password, Character.MIN_VALUE);
    try{
        SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512");
        System.out.println("skf return to secure password call: " + skf.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded());
        return skf.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e){
        throw new AssertionError("Error while hashing a password: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        spec.clearPassword();
        System.gc();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `passwordUtils.getSalt(100);` supposed to do? The salt should be computed ONCE whenever a new password is set, the salt should then be stored along with the salted+hashed password and retrieved alongside of it. You then need to use that same salt to combine with the password that the user just entered and hash the result and then compare the result. Right now you either create a new salt everytime, which simply is not going to work or you use the same salt for all users which defeats a big part of salts.

Comment: Sorry, I added the getSalt() function onto the post. I call passwordUtils.getSalt(100) and store it as String slt because I need to pass it to my verifyUserPassword method

Comment: Then read the first part of my comment again and maybe read up on what a salt is supposed to be. You cannot create new salts when a user tries to log in, you need to generate a salt when the users *sets* a password, then store that salt and use it in all future hashing operations for that user.

Comment: I see what you mean. I don't quite understand how I would take a entered password e.g. "password" and then verify it to the hashed version in the database

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/66989/how-does-a-random-salt-work

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

Comment: you take the entered password, ask the database for the stored salt, compute the hash based one the password and the salt and then compare that hash to the stored one.

Comment: Ahhh okay.  I think that makes sense. So when a user signs-up, we would hash their password and also store their salt. When it comes to logging back in, we would then retrieve the salt values used to hash the password and perform salt hashing to the password they entered and then compare. If they match == same password, else login fails. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, the `signup` or `changePassword` methods are the only ones that should call `getSalt` to *generate* a salt - the login part should only leverage the salt that should be available in `rs`. The rest of the code should stay the same.

Comment: Okay, so the users table in the database should have a column that stored the salt which I would then retrieve using rs.getString() and then verify this way? Thanks so much for helping!

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, appreciate it. I was given a pre-made verify function and was told to plug and play but It didn't seem to work. I will adjust the database and program as you suggested. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

After reading taking on board the feedback received under this post. I managed to solve the issue.

I created another column in the database which was storing Users and named the column "saltPassword". This would store the salt used on the password, which can later be retrieved to check password validation.

After storing the hashed password and the salt used in the database when a user registers. It became quite simple to perform password verification.

```
public boolean verifyPassword(String providedPassword, String fromdatabase, String passwordSalt){
    boolean isValid = false;
    String generate = passwordUtils.generateSecurePassword(providedPassword, passwordSalt);
    
    isValid = generate.equals(fromdatabase);
    
    return isValid;
}
```

This function was used for password verification.
It takes the password entered by the user in the password field, the password currently stored in the database (hashed) and the salt used for the password.

It then generates a salted password using the entered password along with the same salt used for the original password in the database. This should produce the same hashed password in the database. We then check that this is the case by applying .equals(fromdatabase) and checking if it's the same as the one in the database. If this is true, then the password is correct and the user can be logged in.